# Check if data record already exists (if no = create | if yes = do nothing)

Tags: database, mongodb, prisma

i currently started with prisma.schema and mongodb

I have two collections with a field relations between Artwork and Like.

first is called "Artwork"

```
model Artwork {
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId

  name        String?

  mediaFile MediaFile[]

  userId String? @db.ObjectId
  user   User?   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  
  like      Like[]
}
```

second is called "Like"

```
model Like {
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId

  userId String? @db.ObjectId
  user   User?   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])

  artwork   Artwork? @relation(fields: [artworkId], references: [id])
  artworkId String?  @db.ObjectId

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

If someone like a artwork i will create the following record in Like collection

```
{
  userId: 'string',
  artworkId: 'string',
}
```

Now i want to prevent, to create the exact same record in the collections table.

Is there a better way than to send a query beforehand if the dataset exists 1:1 like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a combined unique index on `userId` and `artworkId` to only allow a single Like by a user or an artwork like this:

```
model Like {
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId

  userId String? @db.ObjectId
  user   User?   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])

  artwork   Artwork? @relation(fields: [artworkId], references: [id])
  artworkId String?  @db.ObjectId
  

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  @@unique([userId, artworkId])
}
```

Here's a reference for creating [Compound Unique Index](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#unique-1).